# Ошибка с Shared Preferences

Tags: android

Есть Activity с TextView, в котором задан текст путем `.setText()`

Скачиваю из Parse.com текстовую информацию (обновление календаря), текст TextView меняется. Как теперь сохранить новый текст (новое расписание календаря) при выходе из приложения или при новом перезаходе в это же Activity?

У меня следующий способ не работает (все равно вижу, что заново скачивается текст). Что я делаю не так?

```
Integer list_time_table_corr = timetable_reservation_list.get(0);
if (list_time_table_corr == 1) {
    String list_time_table_NEWDATA = newdata.get(0);
    place1text.setText(list_time_table_NEWDATA);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor21 = preferencesTimeTable.edit();
    editor21.putString("timeTable", list_time_table_NEWDATA);
    editor21.apply();

    list_time_table_NEWDATA =
            preferencesTimeTable.getString("timeTable", list_time_table_NEWDATA);
```

Перед `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)` указано следующее:

```
SharedPreferences preferencesTimeTable =
                      getSharedPreferences("timeTable", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Мало что понятно в вопросе. Что конкретно у вас не работает? Нигде не вижу как вы пытаетесь взять значение из Shared Preferences перед запуском скачивания.

Comment: Да, и имена переменных в Java принято писать, разделяя слова не подчёркиванием, а верхним регистром.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, могли бы Вы помочь, объяснив, что и где именно я должен прописать, чтобы моя задумка сработала?

Comment: Вам надо перед `execute` задачи проверить есть ли сохранённое значение. После завершения задачи значение сохранить. Вы это сделали?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет. К сожалению, впервые столкнулся с SharedPreferences. Перед execute нужно следующее: list_time_table_NEWDATA = preferencesTimeTable.getString("timeTable", list_time_table_NEWDATA); Верно? А после скачивания SharedPreferences.Editor editor21 = preferencesTimeTable.edit();
    editor21.putString("timeTable", list_time_table_NEWDATA);
    editor21.apply(); Или я опять не прав?

Comment: Да, перед запуском задачи проверяете, записано ли что-то в преференсы и совпадает ли оно с значением по умолчанию. Если нет - запускать задачу и результат в onPostExecute сохранять. И попробуйте вместо `apply` использовать `commit`.